# How to Align Circles in table columns to the left?

Tags: html, html-table, alignment

I am new to html and trying to create a table of events that are presented as circles.
I used this code to create each circle :

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style='column-width: 3px;padding-top: 30px;text-align: left;'>
      <svg width='50' height='50'>
        <circle cx='2' cy='2' r='2' fill='#ff8B45'/>
        <title>date</title>
        </svg>
    </td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is that I cant find a way to align them to the left, they start from the right of the table and the more circles there is it goes more to the right... I want it to start from the left leaving space on the right. can anyone tell me how do I make that happen?

Comment: I added borders to `td` and `svg` to help visualize result.

Comment: You're closing your table cell twice. Good formatting is important.

Comment: Looks aligned to me. BTW `column-width` does not apply to table columns, only [CSS Multi-Column layouts](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-multicol/#cw)